# Laravel Specify foreign key for relationship

Tags: laravel, relationship, models

I have a tiny problem which I am having trouble fixing, how do I explicitly specify a foreign key for a model in Laravel 5.2 .. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5):

You can see a lot of examples for every kind of relationship in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships). For example, for One-to-One relationship it will be:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key');
```

Or:

```
return $this->hasOne('App\Phone', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.. I'll spend more time on the documentation from now on :) ..